# React.js useState function passed as a parameter doesn't rerender its component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

So what I'm trying to do is to have a component that renders a list of games.

The component calls the function `ApiMMO.getGamesFromTo()` from a separate script passing the `(response)=>{setGameList(response)}` as a parameter. This separated scripts does a request and uses the function passed as parameter to change the component's state. The script does the job and the console logs confirm that the `gameList` changed but the component doesn't rerender.

The way I know the component didn't rerender is because the `GameCard` component prints its props when mounted.

So here's the code:

```
function GameLibrary(){
    const [gameList, setGameList] = React.useState([]);
    const [gamesPerPage, setGamesPerPage] = React.useState(20);
    const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = React.useState(1);

    // setgameList(ApiMMO.getGamesFromTo( gamesPerPage, pageIndex))

    React.useEffect(() => {
        ApiMMO.getGamesFromTo( gamesPerPage, pageIndex, ((response)=>{setGameList(response)}))
      }, [])

    React.useEffect(()=> {
        console.log('gameList changed: ');
        console.log(gameList);
    },[gameList])

    return(
        <div>
            { gameList.length > 0 ? (
                gameList.map(item => {
                <GameCard game={item}/>
            })) : (
                <GameCard game={'no prop'}/>
            ) }
        </div>
    );
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the `ApiMMO.getGamesFromTo()` code:

```
function getGamesFromTo(numPerPage, page, callback){
    let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://mmo-games.p.rapidapi.com/games',
        headers: {
          'x-rapidapi-host': 'mmo-games.p.rapidapi.com',
          'x-rapidapi-key': rapidapiUserKey
        }
      };

    axios.request(options).then(function (response) {

        let from = (page - 1) * numPerPage;
        let to = page * numPerPage;
        let pageArray = response.data.slice(from, to)
        console.log("REQUEST RESULT: " + pageArray)
        callback(pageArray)
        return pageArray;

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: We may need to see what `ApiMMO.getGamesFromTo` is doing and what is passed to the callback function. Unless you've already verified that `response` is the value you expect/want. I highly doubt the React state update is broken.

Comment: @DrewReese Understood. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Can you verify/validate that the logged `pageArray` value is the same as `response` in the React code? I don't see anything overtly suspicious here. Any errors in the network tab or console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return some value on the map, or else remove the braces `{}`

Replace this:

```
return(
        <div>
            { gameList.length > 0 ? (
                gameList.map(item => {
                <GameCard game={item}/>
            })) : (
                <GameCard game={'no prop'}/>
            ) }
        </div>
    );
```

By this:

```
return(
    <div>
        { gameList.length > 0 ? (
            gameList.map(item => 
             <GameCard game={item}/>
        )) : (
            <GameCard game={'no prop'}/>
        ) }
    </div>
    );
```

Or this:

```
return(
        <div>
            { gameList.length > 0 ? (
                gameList.map(item => {
                 return <GameCard game={item}/>
            })) : (
                <GameCard game={'no prop'}/>
            ) }
        </div>
        );
```

Comment: That was it, thank you very much. I didn't even consider that it was the map's fault, you saved me a huge amount of time.

Comment: No problem. It happened to me thousands of times, haha.

What Mark Williams tells you is also true. You are going to execute the call to the api millions of times (in each render)
Keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Can you change `getGamesFromTo()` so it doesn't need the callback and just returns the response?

Then in your useEffect you could just have:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const getGames = async () => await ApiMMO.getGamesFromTo(gamesPerPage, pageIndex)
  setGameList(getGames())
}, [setGameList, gamesPerPage, pageIndex])
```

-edit- Updated the answer to add an async function inside useEffect so my answer should now work.

Comment: I just tried it but it seems the setGameList() didn't wait for the ApiMMO.getGamesFromTo() to complete the request before running and it assigned an empty value.

Comment: Would require making `getGamesFromTo` `async` so it can `await` the GET request or simply returning the axios Promise chain, either way, it wouldn't work as written above as that would only save the returned Promise object into state. You would need to either continue the Promise chain or wrap in an `async` function in the effect callback.

Comment: I'll try that. It seems like it would be more organized not to send the setGameList() as parameter.